# Método não age da maneira esperada

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando vou checar o seguinte código, não há nada em nenhuma das `ComboBoxes`. Para mim, está tudo normal, não vejo nada de errado, o que pode ser?

```
public FormExemplo()
{
    ExemploList = new List<string[]>;
    CmbB.Enabled = false;
}
private void AttCmbA(ComboBox A) 
{
    A.Items.Clear();
    for (i = 0; i < ExemploList.Count; i++)
    {
        A.Items.Add(ExemploList[i][0]);
    }
} 
private void AttCmbB(ComboBox A, ComboBox B) 
{
    B.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ExemploList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (A.SelectedItem.Equals(ExemploList[i][0]))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                CmbB.Add(ExemploList[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
} 
private void CmbA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CmbB.Enabled = true;
    AttCmbB(CmbA, CmbB);
}
private List<string[]> ExemploList;
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ExemploList.Add(new string[3] { (2 * i).ToString(), (2 * (i++)).ToString(), (2 * (i * i).ToString() });
    }
    AttCmbA(CmbA);
}
```

Comment: Testei o seu código com duas `comboboxes` e um botão a chamar `AttCmb()` e funcionou da forma esperada, as duas `comboboxes` foram preenchidas com "Exemplo". Era suposto o resultado final ser diferente? Como é que está a chamar o código?
Estou a assumir que a forma como os métodos estão declaradas foi só para o SOPT e não estão assim no código.

Comment: Agora está exatamente igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que encontrei no seu código foi no método `AttCmbB(...)`. Aceder à propriedade SelectedItem da forma como tem, devolve nulo porque nesta altura a selecção ainda não foi feita (estamos dentro do evento `SelectedIndexChanged`).

Uma solução será mudar o evento e o método para esta forma:

```
private void AttCmbB(ComboBox B, object selectedItem)
{
    B.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ExemploList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (selectedItem.Equals(ExemploList[i][0]))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                CmbB.Items.Add(ExemploList[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    AttCmbB(CmbB, comboBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Desta forma, utiliza o objecto que originou o evento para ir buscar o valor que foi seleccionado (que após o evento completar fica disponivel na CmbA).

Comment: Quanto à `CmbA`? Quando o `Btn_Click` é acionado, nada acontece. No método `Btn_Click` não há, de fato, aquele _for_, coloquei só para representar uma pessoa que populou o _ArrayList_ previamente.

Comment: Corri o seu codigo e a CmbA está a ser populada correctamente. O problema pode estar nesse `ArrayList` que falou. Coloque o breakpoint nele (dentro do evento de click e veja se está correctamente preenchida).